# What leads to the conclusion that the field associated with a changing magnetic is an electric field that obeys Gauss's law?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's experiments demonstrated that when there is a changing magnetic field, stationary charges experience forces, hence there is a field (force per unit charge) associated with a changing magnetic field. From this, why is the field associated with a changing magnetic field also called an electric field, since the only definition of an electric field seems to come from electrostatics and therefore an electric field is curl-less, but the field associated with a changing magnetic field is not curl-less. The footnote in the image (from the 3rd ed. of Griffiths's electrodynamics) explains this but there's no explanation why the field is divergence-less. In the 4th ed. of Griffiths's electrodynamics, it is simply stated that the field associated with a changing magnetic field obeys Gauss's law, so the divergence of the field (with charge density equals zero) is zero, but how is it known that the field obeys Gauss's law?
[image]

Comment: I am not sure about this but I think that since the only measurable property of the G field is its curl, the divergence can be set to be anything. Though if you derive maxwell's equations directly from SR as done by Ohanian and Schwartz then you can see that E and G indeed are the same.

Comment: If we construct a nonuniform magnetic field (eg. from an unevenly shaped magnet) then shoot an electron through an opening between the magnets, the electron is deflected. So if this is not the same coulomb electric force the electron is experiencing, then there must be some new type of hitherto unknown force that also affects charge...

Comment: *The only definition of an electric field seems to come from electrostatics.* Why do you think that? Electric and magnetic fields are defined by the forces that they exert on charged particles; i.e.  the Lorentz force law.

Comment: @Ghoster In Griffiths's electrodynamics, the only definition of an electric field, as far as I've read, came from Coulomb's law. If I haven't misunderstood you, an electric field is any vector **v** that satisfies **F** = q**v** (**F** is an electromagnetic force)? If that's so, since electric fields associated with changing magnetic fields are not curl-less, whereas electric fields attributable to charges are, how can we know that the former obeys Gauss's law like the latter?

Comment: Gauss’ Law has nothing to do with the curl of the field.

Comment: I don’t mean they are related to each other, but as an example that electric fields associated with changing magnetic fields can have different properties from electric fields attributable to charges. How can we then know that they follow the same rule for the divergence?

Comment: Because Maxwell’s equations say they do, and experiments confirm Maxwell’s equations. Are you suggesting that Maxwell’s equations are wrong? In physics, we “know” something when it agrees with experiment.

Comment: Speaking purely theoretically, without caring about experiments… You could perhaps invent an ugly theory where electric fields produced by charges have a divergence, and electric fields produced by changing magnetic fields do not. However, I doubt that you could construct such a theory that is Lorentz covariant (i.e., consistent with Special Relativity). SR places severe constraints on how an EM field can behave.

Comment: I'm not suggesting Maxwell's equations are wrong. I just want to know the basis for the assertation that electric fields associated with changing magnetic fields obey Gauss's law or what led Maxwell to that. Would appreciate it if you could help me on that.

Comment: [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) might be an appropriate place to ask what led Maxwell to that, since this is a question not about physics but about the history of physics.

Comment: Personally, I think that saying “there are really two distinct types of electric field” is a very misleading way to describe the physics. My point of view is that there is *one* type of electric field; its divergence is determined by charge density and its curl is determined by the rate of change of the magnetic field. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Fields_with_prescribed_divergence_and_curl) for how these two things plus vanishing at infinity uniquely determine the field. I like to think that this is how Maxwell thought about it, but I don’t know that.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information!